# How can I send SMS messages from my real phone number, not my Google Voice number?

Tags: cyanogenmod, sms, google-voice, oneplus-one

This question is precisely the opposite of the existing question: "How can I send SMS messages from my Google Voice number without using the Voice app?"

Since installing the Google Voice app, text messages that I send from the ordinary Messaging app are coming from my Google Voice number. I don't know how or why - no setting I can find in the messages app mentions GV or my GV number.

- I currently use my OnePlus One's built-in Messaging app for SMS. I installed Hangouts and Google Voice, but both are NOT configured for SMS. (I use Google Voice occasionally, but I still use my real cell number directly for most calls and texts to my friends.)
- In the "Messaging" app settings, it says "SMS Enabled."
- In the "Hangouts" app settings, it says "SMS Disabled."
- In the "Google Voice" SMS view, it says, "You are now receiving SMS in Hangouts." This is obviously not true, but doesn't seem relevant to my problem either. (I'm guessing that the writers of that particular message couldn't conceive of any SMS app other than GV or Hangouts. :)
- When I actually receive messages, I get them in the "Messaging" app as expected. When I reply to those messages, which were sent to my AT&T number, my replies come from my GV number, confusing my friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further digging, I found the answer. In the settings app under "wireless and networks," there is a setting: "Enable all apps to send SMS messages through Google voice." Disabling this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are using the default messaging app, open hangouts and go into the settings and check under `Send SMS From`.

It should say send from Carrier, if it says Google Voice, the default app could use that number.

[image: Carrier]

Also, you may want to try to click on SMS Enabled and set it to disabled if it says enabled.

Comment: The hangouts app had "SMS Disabled," which meant that "Send SMS From" wasn't even an available option.